# Why does this happen in a python logic statement?

Tags: python, logic

Can someone please tell me why this doesn't work? I'm trying to make it so that the user can only type in 'Sign in' or 'Register,' and will receive the error message when anything else is typed in.

```
while A == False:
        print('Would you like to create an account or sign in to a preexisting one?')
        print('Sign in')
        print('Register')

        R = input()

        if R == 'Sign in' or 'Register':
            A = True
        else:
            print('')
            print('###################################')
            print('Error: please enter a valid keyword')
            print('###################################')
            print('')
            continue
```

Comment: `if R == 'Sign in' or R == 'Register'` or `if R in ['Sign in', 'Register']`

Answer (score 0):

The statement: `R == 'Sign in' or 'Register'` is being interpreted as: 
`'Register' != ''` or `R == 'Sign in'` and because 'Register' is never equal to '' this will always return True. I would recommend `R in ('Sign in', 'Register')`, but you could also use `R == 'Sign in' or R == 'Register'`.

Comment: actually, `R == 'Sign in' or 'Register'` will just always return `True` or 'Register', so the if statement will *always* run --- because 'Register' is Truthy

Comment: @importhanjuuryoku `'Register' != ''` is always true so yes it will always return true. And technically `R == 'Sign in' or 'Register'` will only return `'Register'` if `R != 'Sign in'`, but in this case `or` is being used in an if statement so the actual value doesn't matter in this case.

Comment: @Dragonbreath547 Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer solved your issue, you can mark it as accepted.